# SQL: I Need to calculate the change in a value compared to the previous row where the qualifiers are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code, adapted from another's answer on these forums. However it is telling me that"
"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '('."

I am new to SQL and I cant find the error any help fixing it would be greatly appreciated.

"cteMain: I dont know what that is or what it is referencing, VieClaimTrans is a VIEW of TrnClaimTrans which is where the all the information im working with is stored."

```
WITH cteMain AS

(SELECT sn.ClientID , sn.FileNo, sn.ClaimNo, sn.TransEstimate, sn.TransType, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sn.TransType, sn.ClientID, sn.FileNo, sn.ClaimNo ORDER BY sn.ClientID, sn.FileNo, sn.ClaimNo)
FROM VieClaimTrans AS sn)

SELECT m.ClientID, m.FileNo, m.ClaimNo, m.TransType, 
   ISNULL(sLag.TransEstimate, 0) AS prevEstimate,
  (m.TransEstimate - ISNULL(sLag.TransEstimate, 0)) AS movement
FROM TrnClaimTrans AS m

LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMain AS sLag
ON sLag.ClientID = m.ClientID
AND sLag.FileNo = m.FileNo
AND sLag.ClaimNo = m.ClaimNo
AND sLag.sn = m.sn-1
```

---

Comment: you are subtracting 1 from a table in this part: `m.sn-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a comma in-front of ROW_NUMBER()

```
;WITH cteMain AS

(SELECT sn.ClientID , sn.FileNo, sn.ClaimNo, sn.TransEstimate,
```

--you should add your comma before row_number(), cheer

```
sn.TransType, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sn.TransType, sn.ClientID, 
sn.FileNo,sn.ClaimNo ORDER BY sn.ClientID, sn.FileNo, sn.ClaimNo) '[ROWNAME]'
```

--add your variable name after row_number()

```
FROM VieClaimTrans AS sn)

SELECT m.ClientID, m.FileNo, m.ClaimNo, m.TransType, 
ISNULL(sLag.TransEstimate, 0) AS prevEstimate,
(m.TransEstimate - ISNULL(sLag.TransEstimate, 0)) AS movement
FROM TrnClaimTrans AS m

LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMain AS sLag
ON sLag.ClientID = m.ClientID
AND sLag.FileNo = m.FileNo
AND sLag.ClaimNo = m.ClaimNo
AND sLag.sn = m.sn-1
```

Comment: Changed that. It now says that "Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
No column name was specified for column 6 of 'TrnClaimTrans'."

Comment: Thanks that worked. I did however also remove everything but TransType from the Partition statement which made it work as desired. Thanks for the help.